# Flutter golden tests failing on CI

Tags: flutter, circleci, flutter-test

I recently added a bunch of golden file tests (and generated the goldens by running `flutter test --generate-goldens`) to my Flutter plugin. All of the tests successfully pass on my development device, but consistently fail when they run on Circle CI (for example: https://circleci.com/gh/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/78).

Am I missing a step in creating the golden tests? Or is there maybe a configuration option I need to add to Circle CI in order for the image files to be added correctly?

Comment: I forgot to note, both my machine and the test machine are running the same flutter version.

Comment: [Flutter golden image tests diff threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73048760/14052058) added from duplicate answer by [yshean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14052058/yshean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on operating system (windows, macos or linux) flutter generates different golden images. Usually CI services use linux machines or macos if you build for iOS. So you need just use the same OS as CI to generate golden images.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Flutter documentation that states this?

Comment: it's mentioned in flutter [wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Writing-a-golden-file-test-for-package:flutter#adding-a-new-golden-file-test) and also came from our experience with Codemagic CI/CD

```
...Otherwise, the golden file test will be skipped on local platforms that are not Linux. This is due to slight rendering differences across platforms ...
```

Comment: I think I read somewhere that this is fixed now, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OSX the default font smoothing can be enabled. It looks flutter is using that setting too in golden tests.

So that a quick fix is to disable font smoothing:

```
defaults -currentHost write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an old Flutter ORB on `CircleCI`. Flutter ORB is set to `1.0.2` and it looks like your code needs `3.0.0`. I took the liberty to run your code using that ORB and it worked. I mean, I saw some errors but they are related to the tests.

You just need to update your https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml#L3 to:

```
  codecov: codecov/codecov@3.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @Mikhail's answer above, since not everyone can afford to have the same OS when running the golden tests on a CI server, I found this related question and posted a solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73048760/14052058

A snippet of the solution:

1. Put this somewhere in your test folder

```dart
  import 'dart:typed_data';
    
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
    
    /// Works just like [LocalFileComparator] but includes a [threshold] that, when
    /// exceeded, marks the test as a failure.
    class LocalFileComparatorWithThreshold extends LocalFileComparator {
      /// Threshold above which tests will be marked as failing.
      /// Ranges from 0 to 1, both inclusive.
      final double threshold;
    
      LocalFileComparatorWithThreshold(Uri testFile, this.threshold)
          : assert(threshold >= 0 && threshold <= 1),
            super(testFile);
    
      /// Copy of [LocalFileComparator]'s [compare] method, except for the fact that
      /// it checks if the [ComparisonResult.diffPercent] is not greater than
      /// [threshold] to decide whether this test is successful or a failure.
      @override
      Future<bool> compare(Uint8List imageBytes, Uri golden) async {
        final result = await GoldenFileComparator.compareLists(
          imageBytes,
          await getGoldenBytes(golden),
        );
    
        if (!result.passed && result.diffPercent <= threshold) {
          debugPrint(
            'A difference of ${result.diffPercent * 100}% was found, but it is '
            'acceptable since it is not greater than the threshold of '
            '${threshold * 100}%',
          );
    
          return true;
        }
    
        if (!result.passed) {
          final error = await generateFailureOutput(result, golden, basedir);
          throw FlutterError(error);
        }
        return result.passed;
      }
    }
```

2. Put this in `test/flutter_test_config.dart` (create one if not already exist)

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'utils/local_file_comparator_with_threshold.dart';

/// Customise your threshold here
/// For example, the error threshold here is 0.5%
/// Golden tests will pass if the pixel difference is equal to or below 0.5%
const _kGoldenTestsThreshold = 0.5 / 100;

Future<void> testExecutable(FutureOr<void> Function() testMain) async {
  if (goldenFileComparator is LocalFileComparator) {
    final testUrl = (goldenFileComparator as LocalFileComparator).basedir;

    goldenFileComparator = LocalFileComparatorWithThreshold(
      // flutter_test's LocalFileComparator expects the test's URI to be passed
      // as an argument, but it only uses it to parse the baseDir in order to
      // obtain the directory where the golden tests will be placed.
      // As such, we use the default `testUrl`, which is only the `baseDir` and
      // append a generically named `test.dart` so that the `baseDir` is
      // properly extracted.
      Uri.parse('$testUrl/test.dart'),
      _kGoldenTestsThreshold,
    );
  } else {
    throw Exception(
      'Expected `goldenFileComparator` to be of type `LocalFileComparator`, '
      'but it is of type `${goldenFileComparator.runtimeType}`',
    );
  }

  await testMain();
}
```

Hopefully this would help people who are looking for a solution to fix the failing golden tests on their CI pipeline because of a small rendering difference.

Comment: When you find another post on Stack Overflow which solves the problem, please vote/flag to close as duplicate instead of adding an answer.

Comment: I don't have the option to vote or flag, maybe my reputation is too low?

Comment: Flagging is always possible. Below the question you should see a "Flag" link which opens a dialog where you can pick "a duplicate".

Comment: Nope, sorry I don't see that Flag link below the question. I can only see the Flag link below my own answer.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. You need 15 rep to flag. Nevertheless, posting an answer which only points to a place where the real answer can be found is not allowed on SO. The correct comment should have been: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. -- from review"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I should edit the answer by including the solution itself then?

Comment: Do no post links to other StackOverflow answers, or "only" code from another answer, as a new answer. When you have a high enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), from making quality contributions, you will be able to leave [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), or [flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as duplicates. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32290908)

Comment: The link was added as a comment.